# realtime syslog analytics deployment not working

Tags: juju, aws, continuous-deployment

@Galgalesh; I am trying these bundle ( https://jujucharms.com/realtime-syslog-analytics/ )from jujucharm.com not custom.  I tried to deploy on AWS didnt work.

## juju --version

1.25.6-xenial-amd64

```
 root@ubuntu:~# juju-1 deploy realtime-syslog-analytics --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro' ERROR cannot resolve charm URL "cs:trusty/realtime-syslog-analytics": charm not found
```

See attachment[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "*juju deploy 'bundle'* " syntax is available only for Juju 2.0 for Juju 1.25 deploying a bundle is done using "*juju quickstart 'bundle'* ". Here is what deploying the bundle using quickstart looks like on my local environment.

```
#> juju quickstart realtime-syslog-analytics                                                                                                                      
juju quickstart v2.2.4
contents loaded for bundle realtime-syslog-analytics/bundle (services: 9)
reusing the already bootstrapped local environment
retrieving the environment status
connecting to wss://10.0.3.1:17070/environment/bd6ed64e-1f10-4911-88f4-bc682cc05ab0/api
environment type: local
bootstrap node series: xenial
charm URL: cs:trusty/juju-gui-130
service juju-gui already deployed
reusing unit juju-gui/0
juju-gui/0 is ready on machine 1
unit placed on 10.0.3.165
machine 1 is started
the Juju GUI is ready: retrieving service configuration

Juju GUI URL: https://10.0.3.165
username: admin
password: adm-098d7faa6a744fa1ab86bd23f4e3e852

connecting to the Juju GUI server
requesting a deployment of bundle realtime-syslog-analytics/bundle with the following services:
  flume-hdfs, flume-syslog, namenode, plugin, resourcemanager, rsyslog-forwarder, slave, spark, zeppelin
bundle deployment request accepted
use the GUI to check the bundle deployment progress
more details about this bundle can be found at
  https://jujucharms.com/realtime-syslog-analytics/bundle
opening the browser at
https://10.0.3.165/?authtoken=62249182ecb8485399bbff1e5663a07e
done!

Run "juju quickstart -e local" again if you want
to reopen and log in to the GUI browser later.
Run "juju quickstart -i" if you want to manage
or bootstrap your Juju environments using the
interactive session.
Run "juju destroy-environment local [-y]"
to destroy the environment you just bootstrapped.
```

Here is a short video tutorial on what quickstart is and how to use it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVknLr1spPo

## To deploy a bundle in an existing environment

Supply the environment using the `-e <environment-name>` flag.

```
juju-quickstart -e amazon realtime-syslog-analytic
```

Or use the juju-gui, select the bundle from the Juju GUI and deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  How's about I already have environment at AWS?  How can I enter bundle to juju bootstrap command?  thanks again.

Comment: I've added the instructions to deploy a bundle into an existing environment. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Galgalesh thanks.. I will try and let you know.. Yes thats what I want.